# Build a text-editor in my website

Tags: php, html, text-editor

Ok, I have a website that uses no Framework or CMS because it is a simple site that just displays some text. Nothing more, nothing special for what you would need a real CMS for.

But when I want to change some text I don't want to download the file, edit it in PhpStorm and then reupload it. So I wanted to ask if there's a minimalistic framework that enables this for me without too much time effort.

Comment: use slim micro-framework

Comment: *"But when I want to change some text I don't want to download the file, edit it in PhpStorm and then reupload it."* So what you need is a Content Management System...

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want a big one like WordPress. Is there a slim one like cutenews but even more slim?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with that.

I used CutePHP.

I suggest you to browser over here

[Top 10 simple CMS](http://www.cmscritic.com/top-10-simple-cms/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own CMS then as that is exactly what you are describing.

It should be a simple matter of creating a database table:

```
create table mypages(url VARCHAR(128),content TEXT)
```

You can then echo the content field as your page when needed.

```
SELECT content FROM mypages WHERE url='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}'
```

Updating could be as basic as dumping the content into a textarea in a simple HTML form.  Handle login with .httaccess for simplicity and Robert's your father's brother.  If you have problems writing the code then just ask here!

I reckon this is an hour or two of programming at best.

I do think that time would be better spent though, if you were to learn to use Drupal instead.  Drupal is free, takes about 10 minutes to install and about 6-10 hours to get your first web pages running properly.  Less if you are not fussy about themes.  It is easy to use and yet was good enough to power the White House site.
Better yet, it's written in PHP so its easy to follow and understand.

The real advantage of doing it this way is that though there is a very steep learning curve as for any major CMS, once you are up there, you can do so much more so much faster.  You need only learn it once, after all.